# How fast can I travel to incubate eggs in Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

I bike to work often, and thought hatching eggs on my ride would be a great way to use up all these eggs I'm collecting....  But, even though I kept my phone on for my 20km ride, the incubator said I moved about 2km during my ride.

I am assuming this is because biking is too fast for incubation?  Do we know what a top speed for incubation is?

Answer (score 0):

This [web page](https://www.primagames.com/games/pokemon-go/tips/pokemon-go-best-way-hatch-eggs) seems to imply that the top speed is 12 mph.  Since I ride at about 18 mph, this is a problem for me.  But probably not for other bikers.